# What is an eigensystem? Could you provide a simple example?

Tags: terminology, definition, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvectors

Also, what is the difference between an [eigensystem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigensystem) and the [eigenspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: "eigensystem" can be interpreted in at least 2 ways ("basis of eigenvectors", the set "eigenvectors + eigenvalues"). Mathematica goes with the second "definition", https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a vector space. Since you're asking in the Physics SE an obvious example would be a Hilbert space, though there are lots of other such examples e.g. the normal modes of an oscillating system.

Now suppose we have some operator $\mathbf{T}$, then we have the eigenvectors $\psi$ of $\mathbf{T}$ defined by:

$$ \mathbf{T}\psi = \lambda\psi $$

where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues. For a given eigenvalue the set of all eigenvectors $\psi$ of $\mathbf{T}$ with that eigenvalue is called the *eigenspace* for that eigenvalue. That is, an eigenspace is associated with the operator $\mathbf{T}$ and a single eigenvalue.

The *eigensystem* is the set of all the eigenvectors paired with their eigenvalues i.e. the set of all pairs $(\psi_i, \lambda_i)$.

Answer (score -1):

Eigenspace = eigenvectors
Eigensystem = eigenvalues + eigenvectors.

Comment: +1 . note: this is also the interpretation of Mathematica: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html

Comment: Possibly, but this is not the most helpful answer I've ever seen.

Comment: @JohnRennie so far it is the only answer... despite a few downvotes.

Comment: @JohnRennie it says what it should be said. In the end "eigensystem" is a bit of a loose term. Typically it refers to a basis of eigenvectors (or eigenfunctions) or to the set of all eigenvectors with their relative eigenvalues (this info is for @ NirvanicUniverse ). In the end, this is a legit answer, given the question.

Comment: @Quillo It does answer the question. John (and other downvoters presumably) do not find it to be very helpful though. There is a distinction.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Please do not accuse me of downvoting. As it happens I did not downvote Roger's answer, but in any case the SE rules forbid accusing others of downvoting whether or not the accusation is justified.

Comment: @JohnRennie Sorry, I intended the parenthetical to separate you from the downvoters, but I can see how it was taken that way. I promise no accusation was intended to be made :) The intent was "other users who downvoted", not "other users who also downvoted"

Comment: @JohnRennie I think it is a low-level question, and I am not going to fight for my answer. Though, it is an answer, and as such is not suitable for comments section.

Comment: @RogerVadim OK now it's my turn to get downvotes :-)

Comment: @ BioPhysicist  My comments were primarily intended to be a complement to Roger's answer, (everybody is free to downvote whatever they may dislike). Unfortunately, I have upvoted the new (good) answer of @JohnRennie  .. but it immediately got also a downvote despite it being completely correct and clear.. so yes, sometimes downvotes follow a strange/biased dynamics, but we can only accept this fact :-)